# offset x to an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset

How can i bound this character to flow only in x-direction.
It is now freely moving in all directions.
I want stickman character to be in bottom ( standing upon boundary), and not to move in any direction except x-direction.

It should be jumping in y-direction also.

I am trying to add offset x direction to it.

Here is my fiddle-

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/n52bK/)

Code i am trying-

```
function key(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    e.offsetx;
    var $key = e.keyCode;
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: You had several errors in your JSFiddle code. Your example didn't work for me. Here is a working example -> [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n52bK/1/)

Comment: @da_re, you have same fiddle i have. It shouldn't be error.

Comment: No I have definitively not the same code. I'm getting different errors: `ReferenceError: rightKey is not defined` and this line is also wrong: `function(){ key(event); }` because at this point, there is no `event` variable available. I changed it to `function(event){ key(event); }`. I really don't know hat you are trying. If you want to move the image only to the left or to the right, remove the if blocks `if(upKey)` and `if(downKey)`. `Offset` is for mouse position, is this really what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the css `box.css("top","-=10");` and it should just move in x-direction.

for the jumping you can save the offset on startup like this:

```
var xPos=box.offset().top;

//in your interval
if(spaceBar)
{
    box.stop(true,false).animate({top:xPos-50},100, function(){
       box.animate({top:xPos},100);
    });
}
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n52bK/4/)